# $f_n(x) = n^{1/p}\chi(nx)$ in $L^p(\mathbb{R})$ weakly converges to 0 for $1 \leq p <\infty$

Tags: measure-theory, lp-spaces

I am trying to show that $f_n(x) = n^{1/p}\chi(nx)$ in $L^p(\mathbb{R})$ weakly converges to 0 when $1<p<\infty$. Here I have let $\chi$ denote the characteristic function on $[0,1]$. So far I have noticed that for $g\in L^q(\mathbb{R})$, for $q$ the conjugate pair of $p$,
$$\int_\mathbb{R} f_n(x) g(x) d\mu(x) = \int_{[0,1/n]}n^{1/p}g(x) d\mu(x) = n^{1/p}\int_{[0,1/n]}g(x) d\mu(x)$$
From here, it seems like we should use some kind of change of variables like $x = u/n$. However, this does not seem to yield the final result. Also, why does the weak convergence fail when $p =1$? Thank you in advance!

Comment: What's the reference measure? The Lebesgue measure?

Comment: @Snoop This is for a general measure $\mu$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$L^{p}(\mathbb  R)$ always refers to $L^{p}$ space w.r.t. Lebesgue measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb R$.

By Holder's inequality, for $p>1$ and  $g\in L_q$ where $\frac1q+\frac1p=1$,  we have  $$ n^{1/p}\int_0^{1/n}g(x) d\mu(x)$$ $$ \leq  n^{1/p}\Big(\int_0^{1/n} |g(x)|^{q}d\mu(x)\Big)^{1/q} \Big(\int_0^{1/n} 1^{p}\Big)^{1/p} $$ $$=\Big(\int_0^{1/n} |g(x)|^{q}d\mu(x)\Big)^{1/q} \to 0.$$

When $p=1$ just take $g \equiv 1$ to see that your integral does not tend to $0$.

Comment: Very simple solution! Thank you so much!

Comment: (+1) Just one comment, the limit on the last expression is $g(0)\mu(\{0\})$ since in the OP's notation $\xi(x)=\mathbb{1}_{[0,1]}(x)$.  Thus, is $\mu(\{0\})$ things are kosher and indeed the limit is $0$.