# $ f_n(x) := n^{\frac{1}{p}} \chi_{[0,1]}(n x) $ weakly converges to $0$ for $p>1$, but not for $p=1$

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces, weak-convergence

As the title says, I am trying to show the weak convergence of the function sequence $ n^{\frac{1}{p}} \chi_{[0,1]}(n x) $, which is supposed to converge to $0$ for $p>1$ but not for $p = 1$. I have found an answer to this question (which was not very helpful to me) under the following post:
[$f_n(x) = n^{1/p}\chi(nx)$ in $L^p(\mathbb{R})$ weakly converges to 0 for $1 \leq p <\infty$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4419665/f-nx-n1-p-chinx-in-lp-mathbbr-weakly-converges-to-0-for-1-le)

I understand the use of Holder's inequality but I don't see why that leads to the limit of the weak convergence condition being zero, since we have an inequality, not an equation. Second I can't seem to immediately see why the integral converges at all, even after susbtituting $q$ for $p$ using the equation $ \frac{1}{q}+\frac{1}{p}=1$. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For the first part, recall Hölder's inequality: Let $p \in \,]1,+\infty[,$ and set $p^{*} = \frac{p}{p - 1}.$ Furthermore, let $x \in L^{p}(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mu)$ and $y \in  L^{p^{*}}(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mu).$ Then $\int_{\Omega} |x(\omega) y(\omega)|\mu(d\omega) \leq \left(  \int_{\Omega} |x(\omega)|^{p} \mu(d\omega) \right)^{1/p} \left(  \int_{\Omega} |y(\omega)|^{p^{*}} \mu(d\omega) \right)^{1/p^{*}}.$ Because $n^{1/p} \int_{0}^{1/n} g(x) \mu(dx) \leq n^{1/p} \int_{0}^{1/n} |g(x)| \mu(dx),$ if the RHS is less than or equal to zero, we are done. I don't I follow your 2nd question

Comment: In the post I mentioned, the result is $\left(\int_0^{1 / n}|g(x)|^q d \mu(x)\right)^{1 / q}$ after using Hölder's inequality. I don't understand why this converges to zero for n to infinity for p>1 and doesn't for p=1. The first part is still somewhat unclear to me since the reason that the right hand sind can't be less than zero is because of the absolute value brackets, but the condition for weak convergence doesn't require a non negative function if I recall correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $1<p<\infty$, [Kavi's solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4419672/121671) is very clear. To recap,  letting $f_n(x)=n^{1/p}\mathbb{1}_{[0,1]}(nx)=n^{1/p}\mathbb{1}_{[0,1/n]}(x)$, he makes use of Hölder's inequality to get
$$\big|\int f_n g\big|\leq\|f_n\|_p\|g\|_q=n^{1/p}\frac1n \|g\|_q=\frac{1}{n^{1-\tfrac1p}}\|g\|_q\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}0$$
for all $g\in L_q$, where $\tfrac1p+\tfrac1q=1$. This means that $f_n$ converges to $0$ in the weak topology $\sigma(L_p,L_q)$.

For $p=1$,  notice that for any continuous bounded function $g$
\begin{align}
n\int\mathbb{1}_{[0,1]}(nx) g(x)\,dx&=\int^1_0 g(x/n)\,dx\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}g(0)
\end{align}
by dominated convergence. This shows that $f_n$ does not converge to $0$ in the weak topology $\sigma(L_1,L_\infty)$. In fact, no  subsequence of $f_n$ converges in $\sigma(L_1,L_\infty)$ for there is not $f\in L_1$ such that $\int f g=g(0)$ for all $g\in C_b(\mathbb{R})$ (The Reisz-Markov representation for example).

In the sense of measures, i.e. $\mu_n(dx)=n\mathbb{1}_{[0,1]}(nx)\,dx$, the sequence $\mu_n$ converges weakly to the probability measure $\delta_0$, which is not absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue's measure.

Comment: I'm sorry if It's very obvious, but I still don't see why the final term in Kavi's solution converges for p>1.

Comment: @hzm: I edited Kavi's solution. See if it clearer now (the case $p>1$).

Comment: I think I get it, thank you for clarifying. The reason the integral isn’t infinite is because g(x) is being raised to the qth power and is in the Lq space correct ?

Comment: @hzm: Yes, that happens in $\|g\|_q=\big(\int|g|^q\Big)^{1/q}$.

Comment: @hzm: For any numerical sequence $a_n$, $a_n\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}0$ iff $|a_n|\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}0$.

Comment: Ah, that clears things up, thanks!!